# HOWTO build Realm Unit Tests in Java

Tags: java, android, testing, orm, realm

i'm trying to get some unit tests going for my [Realm](https://realm.io/) models.  [a testing reference](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#testing-and-debugging) exists, but i unfortunately do not follow it.

it uses many other deps (mockito, powermock, etc) that i dont have available, would-prefer-not-to-use, and dont-care-to-learn-if-i-dont-have-to, of course only if possible.  is there a way i can test without mocking at all?  the imports alone are [~40 lines long](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleActivityTest.java#L21).  i just want to test some methods on my model, maybe do one save and fetch.  a barebones example would be super helpful!

i do use gradle, but the provided gradle file doesn't show the adding of the dependencies required in the example (forgive me if they *do*, but from [what i see](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/build.gradle), many of the plugin and compile resources aren't immediately available).

thanks all! respecfully, cdaringe

Comment: If you are not using Robolectric, you can just make the test like a normal Android test case. Otherwise you need to to mock the Realm classes (since those rely on native libs), or take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1867

Comment: the closure of 1867 would be excellent.  although it still uses roboelectric, by this point i'm fine with that, especially because the required test deps are drop significantly from the existing examples after this PR's closure

Comment: Was doing the same thing today. That example is a treatise in how mocks make tests unreadable, complex, and a drag. Will ask a question about where I got with mine.

Comment: Here is the issue I made:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253617/issue-with-realm-unit-test-on-android