# Issue with Realm Unit Test on Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, realm

Using the JUnit4 Test Runner, the test runs and seems to work, but the query returns no results:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LocationViewInstrumentationTest {

@Rule
public val mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<MapsActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MapsActivity::class.java)

@Rule
var testFolder = TemporaryFolder()


@Test
fun mapViewIsRendered() {
    onView(withId(R.id.map)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}

@Test
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun canSaveLocation() {
    val tempFolder = testFolder.newFolder("realmdata")
    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder(tempFolder).build()
    val realm = Realm.getInstance(config)

    realm.beginTransaction()
    val location = Location("Poppy Manor", 33.2, -121.3, 0.0)

    assertThat(location, not(nullValue()))

    realm.commitTransaction()

    RealmQuery<Location> query = realm.where(Location.class);
    RealmResults<Location> results = query.findAll();
    assertThat(results.size(), equalTo(1));

}
```

Yes I looked at the example project but do not want to add all the dependencies and want my tests to be readable so trying to avoid all the mocks too.

Comment: You didn't write to the Realm in the transaction. Try to add `realm.copyToRealm(location)` before `realm.commitTransaction()`.

Comment: Why didn't you put this in as an answer? I used Realm in Swift, just moved to android and did not see those calls. I saw that method but thought it was for resyncing with the session as it were. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, add the answer. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write to the Realm in the transaction.
Try to add `realm.copyToRealm(location)` before `realm.commitTransaction()`.